# Google OAuth 2 - redirect_uri_mismatch error but the redirect URI in API settings is proper

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I've been following the guide at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow to the point where I have an authorization code sent to my server. Then in PHP I attempt to get the access tokens using the following:

```
    $data = "code=".urlencode(trim($access_code)).
    "&grant_type=authorization_code".
    "&client_id=".urlencode($this->client_id).
    "&client_secret=".urlencode($this->client_secret).
    "&redirect_uri=".urlencode(trim($redirect_uri));

    $curl = curl_init("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true); 
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
```

The redirect_uri is EXACTLY the same in PHP as it is in the redirect uris in the google dev console, but the call always returns:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(21) "redirect_uri_mismatch" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, this is what my google API setting looks like:

```
http://such-nom.com
http://www.such-nom.com
```

And the var passed as $redirect_uri:

```
$redir = 'http://such-nom.com';
```

Edit: It seems the exact same PHP works when the request token is generated serverside rather than through the google button.

Comment: You should URL-encode the values you are putting into another URL as parameters properly (or use `http_build_query`) – otherwise it might generate problems, especially if those values contain characters with special meaning such as `&`.

Comment: Added url encoding, same result as before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was adding a trailing slash and waiting a couple of hours.
So the full list of URLs would look like:

```
http://such-nom.com
http://www.such-nom.com
http://such-nom.com/
http://www.such-nom.com/
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a feeling you've just saved me a few hours :)